# Removing the first characters of a phone number and replace them with zero in PHP subsstr

Tags: php, string, substr

Am working on a PHP application whereby I have a phone number in this format +259890111*** ,, Now am using `substr_replace()` to replace the `+` and `259` with `0` so that the output can be: `0**890111***`.

```
$number = '+259890111***';

$new_number = substr_replace($number, '0', 0, ($number == '+259'));
```

Comment: Will the first few characters be `+259`? Can it ever be something else?

Comment: No it will always be +259

Comment: Try `echo preg_replace("/^\+259/", 0, "+259890111***");`

Answer (score 2):

use `str_replace()` (As OP said ***`it will always be +259`***)

```
<?php

$number = '+259890111***';

echo $new_number = str_replace('+259', '0', $number);
```

https://3v4l.org/gQ8NT

Note:- in case number can be different but will be always 3 digits along with `+` then do like below:

```
$number = '+249890111***';

echo $new_number = substr_replace($number, 0, 0, 3);
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/jOuCK

Comment: Yes. No need for regex

Answer (score 2):

According to OP it's always +259 at the start of the strings.
So we can even use substr.

```
echo "0" . substr($number, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a regex, use `preg_replace` with the regex `/^\+259/` to replace `+259` only when its at the beginning of the string with `0`.

- `^`  - start of the string
- `\+` - literal `+`
- `259` - the number to replace

```php
$result = preg_replace("/^\+259/", "0", $number);
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/b5m2O

Though, you can just use `str_replace()` with `+259`, since the number will never contain non-digits except for `+259` at the start.

```php
$result = str_replace("+259", "0", $number);
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/aJ38G